# Should the novel tag be used in a non-story ID question?

Tags: discussion, tags

The title of [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/191879/why-do-readers-of-starship-troopers-think-juan-johnny-is-filipino) unambiguously refers to the novel that a movie is based on. Should the [novel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/novel) tag be added to underscore this?

Furthermore, if the novel is based on a short story, should a tag be added to specify which one of the three is being discussed?

Comment: From the tag wiki excerpt: _"Use to either identify the media on a [story-identification] question or disambiguate works where the tag covers the novel and its form in other media."_ Worth pointing out though that if the question covers more than one media or accepts answers from other media then media tags are not needed.

Comment: There's only 36 questions in the tag, I don't think we need a tag per media for the franchise and unless it's causing harm/confusion I don't think we need to rush out to retag questions.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot 36 is a bit more than a screenful on a phone.

Comment: Are you asking about *the way that this one question has been tagged* or the way in which this tag should be used in general (which I'd point out it is already covered by the tag wiki itself - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/novel).